# How to define @path annotation for two variables in jar-s

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I want to get two parameter inputs from the user for my rest service.

eg: `restservice/name/id`

User will call;

```
restservice/philip/1000
```

To handle above url request, in my rest service, how should i define @path annotation?

```
@POST
    @Path("/{name}/") -->?
    public void processname() {

    }

@POST
    @Path("/{id}/") ------>?
    public void procesId() {

    }
```

Comment: Why do you need two methods? Why don't you just have one method with `@Path("/{name}/{id}")`? Doesn't make much sense to split it up into two resource methods

Comment: @peeskillet thanks that solves my issue..

Answer (score 0):

```
@POST
@Path("/users/{userId}")
public Response addDevice(@PathParam("userId") Long userId) {

    // your code
    return Response.ok("Success").build();
}
```